# Automatic device provisioning in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am currently trying to test my application in my iPhone. Currently I am using xCode version 4.6.3 with an iPhone 4 and a developer account. I have read from some sources that Apple has made an easier alternative for developers to test their application on their device with the introduction of `Automatic device provisioning` in Xcode 4. So this saves the hassle of creating `Ad Hoc & iTunes App Store distribution`. However in my current version of Xcode, there is no such function and is instead replaced with a `refresh button` that prompts for your developer credentials. Does this works the same way as the Automatic device provisioning that was present in the early versions for Xcode 4?
So another question in order test my application on my device, do I just need to :

1) Click on the refresh button in my Xcode organiser.
2) Enter my developer credentials
3) New profile appear in the list with the name "Team Provisioning Profile: *"
4) Select my device name from the scheme
5) Build and run

Or do I have to go through creating an App ID and a provisioning profile in the developer website and change the Bundle Identifier in the plist to the one which i created in the developer website? ?

Comment: why are you still using xcode4? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to go through the procedure of creating certificate, app id (or wild-card), provisioning profile, or you need to upgrade to Xcode 5.

Doing it manually is much easier than it was a few months ago.

Comment: so what do I need to do that is different from Xcode 4 if I were to upgrade to Xcode5?

Comment: In Xcode 5, the provisioning can all be done automatically for you.